# how can i disable clicking on td of table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have html table like this

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="right">
             Email Address
        </td>
        <td  align="left">
            <div>
                <input type="email" data-theme="b" id="EmailAddress" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

now i have an input inside div inside td when i click inside the input the cursor set on the textbox but if i click on the border of input some times the cursor set on the begeining of the td but not at the input 
[image]

Comment: THIS happens in Google Chrome?

Comment: this happens at all browser ,even at Phone gap

Comment: Do you have a web link to test?

Comment: no but i forgot to tell you that i'm testing on mobile

Comment: is that issue related with chrome ?

Comment: This does not happen with the code posted. There is clearly some styling and quite possibly some JavaScript involved. This is not a real question until a real demonstration of the issue is posted.

Comment: This looks like CSS issue, where the background does not really match the position of the textbox. Without test case to work with, we can't really do anything here. Here is a basis if you like where you can add your actual code and reproduce the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/bfdt4

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure *why* this is happening, since it's a behaviour I've never encountered before (and there's no provided demo with which to test), but a quick workaround, since you're using jQuery anyway:

```
$('td:has("input")').on('focus', function(){
     $(this).find('input').focus();
});
```

Effectively when a `focus` event occurs on a `td` element that contains an `input` element the `input` element is focused, so the cursor *should* appear in the `input` instead of elsewhere in the `td`. It might be worth replacing `focus` with `click`, depending on precisely what's happening though.

Comment: is there any way to disable td?

Comment: Well, *darn!* Is there any chance you can post a representative demo for us to play with? To 'disable' the `td`, you could, I guess, simply `$(this).blur()` to the `click` event. But I don't think that would allow the `input` elements to receive `click` events either.

Comment: A demo is *always* helpful, even if you don't think it is. We can't read your mind, or code, without some example.

Answer (score 1):

hey guys i finally found a solution 
 i have set name to the first input in the form then on action of clicking on any td "only on td border" i have set focus on that first input

```
 $('td:has("input")').live('click', function () {
        try {
            var res = $(event.srcElement).attr('type');
            if (res == null) {
                var _input = document.getElementsByName("ToFocus")[0];
                _input.focus();
            }

        } catch (e) {
        }
    });
```

so after this code when the issue happens it take you to focus to the first input :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your use of *border-radius*, or rather, the value you assign to it.

You can mess around with it your self here: http://jsfiddle.net/UN44W/1/

Long story short, even though your border curves using CSS3, the browser still treats the **actual** real estate of the input field as a square (more specifically, square corners). The more narrow your field from border curve, the more obvious the cursor on the left side will look like it's spilling outside of your actual input (even though it is not).

Conclusion: you cannot do anything about this (that I am aware of) as the CSS is only a mask for design, not function. You probably have a value of 10px for the radius; 5px is a little better and looks less obvious.

```
input {
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px; 
        border:1px solid black;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the td, but the input style! Your input seems to be moz-bordered... So, if the border-radius is 5px for example, add a 5px padding to your input field as follows:

via css

```
input {
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px; 
/*add this*/
       padding-left:5px;
       padding-right:5px;
    }
```

via jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('div input').css('padding','0 5px');
 });
```

Comment: In don't think this will affect your design. Maybe you will need to be more explicit by writing 
    
    td div input{/*padding here*/}